# What Chord uses notes F#/Gb B D?

Tags: chords

What Chord uses the notes F# (lowest) B D(highest)?

I like the sound, but I tried googling it without getting any results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a second inversion [B minor chord](http://www.pianochorddictionary.com/chords/b/minor-inversion2.shtml) (Bm/F♯).

```
X:1
L:1/1
M:
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
"Bm/F#"4[^F B d]|
```

Answer (score 1):

Dom already answered correctly, but I found a [Chord Identifier tool](http://www.scales-chords.com/chordid.php) that you might find useful. Just pick which notes are in the chord and it identifies it. [It correctly recognized your chord as Bm/F#.](http://www.scales-chords.com/findnotes_en.php?n1=F%23&n2=B&n3=D&n4=&n5=&n6=&optbass=1&piano=1)